# Laravel load content using jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, laravel-4

I use laravel 4 and I had some problems to get content from ajax. So I have code from my js like this:

```
$("#ratingTab a").on('shown.bs.tab', function (event) {
        var ratingInsert = "{{ URL::to('ratingInsert') }}";
        $.ajax({
            url: ratingInsert,
            type: 'GET'
        })
        .done(function( data ) {
            console.log( data );
        });
    });
```

I use bootstrap 3. And this is my routes:

```
Route::get('ratingInsert', function()
{
    return View::make('pages.ratingTab');
});
```

And this is my views:

```
<h1>Hello</h1>
```

But after I click on my tab/link (trigger to #ratingTab a), from my console browser, there are not any results. And if I change my route like this:

```
Route::get('ratingInsert', function()
{
    return "<h1>Hello</h1>";
});
```

I get result in my console browser `"<h1>Hello</h1>"`.

So I want to get the same result as `return "<h1>Hello</h1>";` if I use `View::make('pages.ratingTab')`. How to get it work??

Comment: I don't really get what you are trying to achieve but try using $.ajax({ url: ratingInsert,  type: 'GET',  success: function(resp)  {   console.log(resp);  },  error: function(resp, errorThrown)  { console.log('error '+ resp) });

Comment: If I use code I get result like this "error [object Object]". How to fix that?

Comment: what's on your pages.ratingTab page? (or pages/ratingTab, however laravel renders it) that page must not be returning anything, or isn't found.

Comment: What do you mean by any result. An empty response or no response at all?

Comment: Ok thaks, problem resolved. I think the comments in my view has no effect. So after i clean my comment, thats work.